# Android Java InetAddr returns IP with initial Slash

Tags: java, android

[image]

As in the screenshot attached I tried to retrieve gethostname of that IP but InetAddr.getByName inserts an initial slash which wouldn't retrieve getHostName....why InetAddress inserts that slash? Is there a way to get rid that slash out to obtain the getHostName?

Thanks!
Cheers,
Luigi

Edit: then I tried to put code inside an AsyncTask and to convert ip string to byte using getByAddress instead of getByName from a mobile app to a non mobile phone device which should return 'V4M0006' as hostname connected on the local mobile phone's local hotspot:

[image]

Comment: The debugger (screenshot) is using `toString` of `InetAddress` to display the contents of `addr` : here is the `toString` docs from `InetAddress`: `Converts this IP address to a String. The string returned is of the form: hostname / literal IP address. If the host name is unresolved, no reverse name service lookup is performed. The hostname part will be represented by an empty string..`

Comment: Hello Andy! Thank you for your answer....then I wonder why getHostName() and getCanonicalHostName() won't give me hostname of the device since it isn't an android phone or similar but just that device has a visible hostname.... maybe should I use different method than InetAddr to query hostname's device?...

Comment: From your code I see you are starting with an IP address - so `getByName` is not a good choice because it expects a host name (and gets the IP address).  What I'd say you want is to use `addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(byte[])` (you'll have to form the byte array from your string) and then use `addr.getHostName()` which will use a reverse name lookup (assuming you have DNS configured).

Comment: Hello Andy... as I re-edited my post adding a new screenshot updating with a test putting code in AsyncTask and also converting that into byte array but it returns still IP as canonicalhostname and hostname when it should return "V4M0006".... if I look on the mobile phone's (Android 11) list inside WiFi Router's settings page I see exatly "V4M0006".... shouldn't return the same thing also getHostName / getCanonicalHostName?....

Comment: You can also use `InetAddress#getHostAddress`.

Comment: thank you dan1st, but I need hostname , not hostaddress , which returns the IP anyway....

Comment: One clue is your device  is on a local lan (192.168...) and the intended lookup target is as well.  You haven't specified the device (android version..) or connection type (wired or wireless) - but in general you'll need to verify the DNS for that network connection on that device is set up properly (typically set to your local lan router).  At this point I'd start a new question pursuing "android devices on local lans dns".

Comment: Hi Andy and thank you again for your answer... in this scenario is a common mobile phone with Android >= 10 with WiFi Router (hotspot) activated by user where sort-of-linux os small devices (not mobile phone) connects to the mobile's hotspot so it's sort of direct connection so then from this app on mobile phone I send to the device some REST API to obtain some informations from device....actually I can get IP and MAC but not hostname yet

Comment: Hi all again.... maybe if it isn't possible to obtain hostname of that external device connected to my mobile phone's WIFI Router hotspot with getHostName(), then is there a way, like with an external C++ library, just if it exists and if it is possible to call external C++ libraries from Android, to obtain that hostname?.... thanks again

Comment: Hello.... no other suggests for my issue?....